# how to query for elements near a point using oracle locator

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I am planning to use oracle locator to index my customer locations in lat long and following the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18750/xe_locator.htm#XELOC100). It explains the case of querying for the customers near a store using

```
-- Find the 3 closest customers to store_id = 101.

SELECT /*+ordered*/ 
   c.customer_id, 
   c.first_name, 
   c.last_name
FROM stores s, 
   customers c
WHERE s.store_id = 101
AND sdo_nn (c.cust_geo_location, s.store_geo_location, 'sdo_num_res=3')
   = 'TRUE';
```

How to do the query if I want all the customers near a location with lat long? Following query did not work

```
SELECT 
   s.store_id
FROM  stores s
WHERE sdo_nn 
  (SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307,      SDO_POINT_TYPE (-71.48923,42.72347,NULL), NULL, NULL), s.store_geo_location, 'sdo_num_res=3', 1) = 'TRUE' ;  2    3    4    5  
SELECT
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-13249: SDO_NN cannot be evaluated without using index
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 17
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.PRVT_IDX", line 9
```

How to query for points near a point with latitude, longitude?

Comment: documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_operat.htm#SPATL1032

Comment: You can specify a distance and the number of results.

Comment: @Rene what if I want to mention the lat long as I wrote in the question?

Comment: You need two geometries. One of the records you want to find, the other as the point of reference. Look at your first query. Customer location, store location. Remove store from that query and add your point geometry.

Comment: @Rene can you please write the query as you commented? I don't understand your comment completely.